# Multi-Language Alert From String Resources

Tags: android, multilingual, getresource

I have an alert. The code works.  I have multiple language folders for strings.  `res/values/strings.xml` & `res/values-es/strings.xml` etc.  This works fine for the UI but the alert title, button titles & alert msg, I would like in other languages also. It keeps coming up in the default language (english). If I try using a String variable & `getResources().getString(R.string.name);`  the app blows. The docs say...  I see others have asked a similar question w/o any response. Anyone know how to fix this? Specify locale or something?

```
public void showSettingsAlert(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    //String title_settings = getResources().getString(R.string.Settings);
    //String title_cancel = getResources().getString(R.string.Cancel);
    //String GPS_settings = getResources().getString(R.string.GPS_Settings);
    //String GPS_not_enabled = getResources().getString(R.string.GPS_not_enabled);
    //String title_settings =getResources().getString(R.string.Settings);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS Settings");
    //alertDialog.setTitle(GPS_settings);

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");
    //alertDialog.setMessage(GPS_not_enabled);

    // On pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    //alertDialog.setPositiveButton(settings, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // on pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    //alertDialog.setNegativeButton(cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Android, resource names cannot contain capital letters. Change your resource names to use lowercase letters and that should fix your problem.